# tab.create was changed? how avoid chrome popup extension to close

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

in my extension, there is a option that to close or unclose popover on clicked a URL.

```
    chrome.tabs.create( {
        url : turl
    });
    if (!settings.get("lockPopover")) {
        window.close();
    }
```

in the latest version chrome v20, it dont work. popover was closed all time.
how to avoid this.

Comment: What is `settings`? It's not a built-in object.

Comment: settings is localStorage

Comment: `localStorage` does not have a `get` method. Show the code behind `settings`. Also, show the code where the `lockPopover` key-value pair is defined.